# Point shapefile problem

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, excel

I have a point shapefile which was created from a text file in Excel using the delimited text layer plugin in QGIS. My problem is that I am getting a point shapefile but when I try to insert this in an India shapefile, the points do not overlay this shapefile. The projections are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what options you have set in `Settings -> Options -> CRS` tab for new **layers**, the delimited text layer will get automatically a preset CRS, or you will be prompted for one.

Change the setting in `Prompt for CRS`, and choose the same CRS as the shapefile has.

Comment: how to go to that option? can u elaborate your answer?

Comment: Settings -> Options -> CRS tab, the lower part of the form.